Using Sequelize to establish foreign key constraint
I'm using the Sequelize ORM to interact with my MariaDB database on a nodeJS project.

The problem is that I want to create two models ( User and Post ) with Sequelize with a foreign key constraint in the second model (Post) but at the level of the Post model I have errors the database cannot take take into account the foreign key constraint!

The codes for my models below..
Here is the code for my User model which is created in the database during the initialization of my application
const validRoles = ['admin', 'normal'];

// Creation of a User model for the users table
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
     return sequelize.define(
         // Model name
         'User',
         // Fields
         {
             user_id: {
                 type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                 primaryKey: true,
                 autoIncrement: true
             },
             username: {
                 type: DataTypes.STRING,
                 allowNull: false,
                 validate: {
                     notEmpty: {
                         msg: 'Username must not be empty!'
                     },
                     notNull: {
                         msg: 'Username is required!'
                     }
                 }
             },
             user_email: {
                 type: DataTypes.STRING,
                 allowNull: false,
                 unique: {
                     msg: 'This username is already taken!'
                 },
                 validate: {
                     isEmail: {
                         msg: 'The email is invalid!'
                     },
                     notNull: {
                         msg: 'Email is required!'
                     }
                 }
             },
             user_password: {
                 type: DataTypes.STRING,
                 allowNull: false
             },
             user_role: {
                 type: DataTypes.STRING,
                 allowNull: false,
                 validate: {
                     isRoleValid(role) {
                         if(!role) {
                           throw new Error('A user must have a role!')
                         }
                         if(!validRoles.includes(role)) {
                             throw new Error(`The type of a pokemon must belong to the following list: ${validRoles}`)
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         },
         // timestamps
         {
             timestamps: true
         }



AND here is the one for the Post model (which poses a problem)

const { gzipSync, gunzipSync } = require('zlib');

// Creation of a Post model for the posts table
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
     return sequelize.define(
         // Model name
         'Post',
         // Fields
         {
             post_id: {
                 type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                 primaryKey: true,
                 autoIncrement: true
             },
             user_id: {
                 type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                 references: {
                     model: 'User',
                     key: `user_id`
                 }
             },
             post_text: {
                 type: DataTypes.TEXT,
                 allowNull: false,
                 validate: {
                     notEmpty: {
                         msg: 'Content must not be empty!'
                     }
                 },
                 get() {
                     const storedValue = this.getDataValue('content');
                     const gzippedBuffer = Buffer.from(storedValue, 'base64');
                     const unzippedBuffer = gunzipSync(gzippedBuffer);
                     return unzippedBuffer.toString();
                 },
                 set(value) {
                     const gzippedBuffer = gzipSync(value);
                     this.setDataValue('content', gzippedBuffer.toString('base64'));
                 }
             },
             post_image: {
                 type: DataTypes.STRING
             },
             post_content: {
                 type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
                 get() {
                     return `${this.post_text} + ' ' + ${this.post_image}`;
                 },
                 set(value) {
                     throw new Error('Do not try to set the `post_content` value!');
                 }
             }
         },
         // timestamps
         {
             timestamps: true
         }
     );
}



As for the error message, here it is

  original: SqlError: (conn:100, no: 1005, SQLState: HY000) Can't create table `groupomania`.`Posts` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
   sql: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Posts` (`post_id` INTEGER auto_increment , `user_id` INTEGER, `post_text` TEXT NOT NULL, `post_image` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`), FOREIG


Could you show the whole sql statement from the error?
